CosmosDB synapse pipeline does not work with Encryption
We have an encrypted Cosmos Db account and when we try to read the data using Azure synapse apache spark , it gives back the encrypted data. We have tried to connect to CosmosDb using System managed identity as well as Account key for simplicity but none of the approach gives back the decrypted data. Also, here we are trying to connect to transactional instance(oltp) instead of analytical store. Does apache spark does not support decryption?

Can you provide some sample data and your approach you have tried so far and did you get any ERROR while attempting?

can you please provide some insights how is the azure cosmos db encrypted?

Are you using CMK or Service-managed key

Hello @DileepRajNarayanThumulam , I am using CMK approach here. It seems Apache spark does not have decryption capabilities towards CosmosDB encryption.

No, you cannot directly decrypt data encrypted with a Customer-Managed Key (CMK) in Azure Cosmos DB within Apache Spark.
Reason: Cosmos DB CMK encryption is designed to be client-managed, requiring you to retrieve the CMK from Key Vault to decrypt data within your Spark application.
Below Image shows how effectively managing the wrapping and unwrapping of Data Encryption Keys (DEKs) and Customer-Managed Keys (CMKs).
below image is reffered from the Use client-side encryption with Always Encrypted for Azure Cosmos DB

Know more about Customer-managed keys
Below client-side migration v2 for decrypt any existing encrypted data:
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    blob_client.require_encryption = True
    blob_client.key_encryption_key = kek
    blob_client.encryption_version = ‘2.0’  # Use Version 2.0!
    with open("decryptedcontentfile.txt", "rb") as stream:
        blob_client.upload_blob(stream, overwrite=OVERWRITE_EXISTING)

Reference: Can Azure Key Vault Encryption Decryption be performed in Databricks?
Encrypting and decrypting a blob with client-side encryption v2
